# ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown || geometry LINE 2: ... WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_BUFFER('|| $1 ||

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Can anyone see what's wrong with the below simple function? Is it a simple syntax error or something else? I'm using postgreSQL 8.4. Thanks in advance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_source_from_closest_road_to_point(IN point geometry)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
      DECLARE --- Nothing to declare
          query varchar;
          rec RECORD;
      BEGIN

      query = 'SELECT p.source FROM project AS p
                         WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_BUFFER('|| $1 ||',0.001),p.the_geom)
                         AND p.clazz NOT IN (''11'',''12'') -- Motorway or motorway entrance exit ways
                         ORDER BY st_distance(st_closestpoint(p.the_geom::geometry, '|| $1 ||'::geometry), '|| $1 ||'::geometry) ASC  LIMIT 1';

      FOR rec IN EXECUTE query LOOP
           RETURN rec.source;
      END LOOP;

      END;   $BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
```

I'm using the command:

```
     explain analyze select * from get_source_from_closest_road_to_point(ST_GeomFromText('Point(-6.3047272 53.4030415)', 4326));
```

But get the error:

```
   ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown || geometry
   LINE 2: ...                     WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_BUFFER('||  $1  ||...
                                                         ^
   HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit      type casts.
   QUERY:  SELECT  'SELECT p.source FROM project AS p
                         WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_BUFFER('||  $1  ||',0.001),p.the_geom)
                         AND p.clazz NOT IN (''11'',''12'') -- Motorway or motorway   entrance exit ways
    '||  $1  ||'::geometry), '||  $1  ||'::geometry) ASC  LIMIT 1'
      C         ONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "get_source_from_closest_road_to_point" line 6 at assignment

      ********** Error **********

     ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown || geometry
      SQL state: 42725
```

Comment: Do you really need to use dynamic SQL inside this function?

Comment: If I don't i won't use the index and it will take about 10 times as much time to perform the search. That's the reason why I'm using the dynamic sql. Can't think of an alternative :(

Comment: I recommend updating to latest versions of Postgres. They have fixes to bad query planning in PL/SQL functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using dynamic SQL with params. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_source_from_closest_road_to_point(IN point geometry)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  src integer;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT p.source FROM project AS p
            WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_BUFFER($1 ,0.001),p.the_geom)
              AND p.clazz NOT IN (''11'',''12'') -- Motorway or motorway entrance exit ways
            ORDER BY st_distance(st_closestpoint(p.the_geom::geometry, $1), $1) ASC  
            LIMIT 1' 
   INTO src
   USING point;
   RETURN src;
END;   
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

It is strange, that you can not use `USING` in `EXECUTE` statement. It is a standard thing for postgres.

Exact from [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html) manual page:

> The command string can use parameter values, which are referenced in the command as $1, $2, etc. These symbols refer to values supplied in the USING clause. This method is often preferable to inserting data values into the command string as text: it avoids run-time overhead of converting the values to text and back, and it is much less prone to SQL-injection attacks since there is no need for quoting or escaping.

I have modified the query to look like the one from the manual - try it now.

Comment: hi Igor, thanks again, can't use USING. 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"

Comment: I'm using a windows platform and pgrouting which is only available up to postgreSQL 8.4 on windows platform.

Comment: @sergiopuy See the updated answer. If it still wont work - tell me, I will try to fix your initial query.

Comment: You're a genius Igor :)) it worked just fine. Same return time as the normal query outside the function. Thanks man, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do this if you want to dynamically build a query string and then execute it is to cast the geometry to text and then back to geometry again, so that it is interpreted as a text character while the string is being built and then converted back to a geometry when actually executed. This is a little bit ugly, but does work, as I had a few issues using the execute '... $1 ...' using geom approach, eg,

```
stmt:='... st_contains(st_geomfromtext(''' || st_astext(geom_param) || '''),geom)...'
execute stmt;
```

My use case is that I have to dynamically generate a save name for a csv file, using copy... to where the file names and enclosing geometry come from a table that is passed in as a paramter, so I can't avoid loops and dynamic SQL creation like this.